# Indesign: Exporting page with image overlaid with text to ePub

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, layout, epub

I am trying to export the following layout to ePub:
[image]

As you can see there are following components to the layout:

1. Chapter number
2. Chapter title
3. Circle with inline and curveline text
4. Body text

However, when trying to export the page to ePub, I get the following mess:
[image]
[image]

I do understand that ePub treats all indesign items in a linear order and hence splits them vertically. Is there any way to retain the layout during export? Any way to retain, say, the first 3 items listed above as a single image leaving the body text reflowable? I tried using the Object Export option but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be both a problem of implementation and design approach.

From the *[International Digital Publishing Forum page](http://www.idpf.org/accessibility/guidelines/content/style/backgrounds.php)*:

> The background-image property remains largely unsupported because of
>   the reflowable nature of EPUBs. Although support may increase as
>   fixed-layout publications get supported, use of images is not
>   recommended in general, reflowable publications.

As the text / image size relationship will vary depending on the renderer (from a tiny smartphone screen to a tablet or computer screen, with varying font size, modifiable by the user), it may not be a good idea to place text over images at all.

In this particular case, you may be able to make an image header with the number 2 and the shoes, putting the rest of the text afterwards without overlaying the image and modifying the circle with the "56 words" in a more elegant way -than the solution offered by InDesign.  It may help to remember that ePub is closer to Dreamweaver than Photoshop capabilities.